# Edit QObject property from qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I was writing some class, which extends QObject and has few Q_PROPERTY
I`m use it in QAbstaction model with one Role (always return QObject* ), in QList;
In QML I would to Bind property with TextEdit, like a :

```
Binding
{
    target :currentReport
    property: description
    value: text_description_edit.text
}
```

But this entry returns error and not bind my property:

```
file:///..somePath../ReportAddDelegate.qml:179: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: description
```

How I can edit my QObject property in qml?

UPD:
im use `property QtObject currentReport` in delegate component

//sorry for my english

Comment: Show property `description` definition. It should have `WRITE`, `READ` and `NOTIFY` sections.

Comment: Yes, it have 
Q_PROPERTY(QString description WRITE setDescription READ getDescription NOTIFY descriptionChanged)

Comment: By the way, if  I write like :
TextEdit
{...
text: curretnReport.description
} 
then I have no error, and I see text in TextEdit, but if I edit it, I don`t edit description property in object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! 
I'm take mistake in Binding !
need write `property: "description"` instead `property: description`

Comment: Nice English though!